# How to make message box in asp.net mvc with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to create message box like this, which has pink background color

[image]

And when display that message box, page is not dark.

Thank you.

Comment: This question is way too broad. There are dozens of JavaScript GUI frameworks that have dialog boxes and still others that have what are commonly referred to as "alert boxes", which basically show a box after a certain event happens. There is no one way to answer this question unless you narrow it down to a specific dialog framework and use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap:

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>Oh snap!</strong> <a href="#" class="alert-link">Change a few things up</a> and try submitting again.
</div>
```

Here is a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/rgBX5DBUoC) as an example.

For **jQuery**, to get a message box, you can use [this](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways:

Use bootstrap model

Check this [w3schools](http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp&ei=8Q2j4n4H&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=107&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1466794326&sig=AKOVD65meFy5oPFe2IGf7a73ymEc9-tDww) link

Or try jquery dialog box:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dialog">   
    <table>  
        <tr>
            <td >Question</td>
            <td colspan="2">Yes/No</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 1</td>
            <td><input name="Input1" style="text-align:center;" type="radio" /></td>
            <td><input name="Input1" style="text-align:center;" type="radio" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 2</td>
            <td><input name="Input2" style="text-align:center;" type="radio" /></td>
            <td><input name="Input2" style="text-align:center;" type="radio" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>   
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
});
```

Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/c5Rnf/)

Comment: thanks for editing . I posted this from my mobile which doesn't understand alignment